# Animating a div to 100% height

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate a div to 100% of its content but it just flashes and rather than animate the div the background disappears at the end of the animation. i am stumped because it works when i enter a number for the height rather than a percentage.

```
$("#artbutton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $self=$(this);
    $("#media").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#music").animate({height:0},"slow",function(){
        document.location = $self.attr('href');
        $("#art").animate({height:"100%"},"slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: the `height` property does rarely work as intended upon `%` useage. Are you sure you can't do this animation with `bottom: 0` or `top: 0`?

Comment: Can you provide more info please? How is your HTML looking like? Which styles do you? Perhaps providing a http://jsfiddle.net would help. Also height:100%; does not work as people wish in most cases.

Comment: add 100% height to the html and body tags and try again

Comment: thanks for everyones help i have fixed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you want to steer clear from using percentages when it comes to height. The problem is the following:

*The div's height is 100%... of what?
**Answer:** 100% of the height of the parent element. OK, great! How high is the parent element? Let's check what the height is of the elements contained within. Hmmm, this child div has its height set to 100%... of what?*

And so the loop continues...

There are two fixes for this:

1. Make sure the parent element has a fixed height (not a percentage, because then it would check the parent above, etc...).
   So you can use height-percentages only if the parent tag has a fixed height.
2. Don't use percentages and just give your div a fixed height.

Or, conversely, you can wrap you div in a new div. Set the parent to a fixed height and the child (the old div) can now use percentage-based height values.

Comment: Thanks,
i ended up using a fixed height. I changed my design slightly anyway and i ended up with a fixed height.

Comment: I've been stuck on this problem in the past. It's tough to spot, but it seems so obvious once you understand it :-)

Answer (score 1):

not sure you can go with percentage, why not get the height value first using JS if the height is not fixed.

```
$height = $('div').height();
```

and then animate the height with a number.

```
$("#artbutton").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $self=$(this);
    $("#media").animate({height:0},"slow");
    $("#music").animate({height:0},"slow",function(){
        document.location = $self.attr('href');
        $("#art").animate({height: $height + 'px',},"slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: The height is fixed to begin with so its hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of setting up an outer div with a defined height was not a possible solution for me.  My php code was a template and the content of my div would always be changing - filed with content from the database that depended on the link the user clicked.  And this div is at the top of the page with other info that must be displayed right under it.

So, I came up with this solution that works very well for me.

First, I removed the set height from the CSS and added "display: none;" - this allowed the div to load fully open, but the user doesn't see it.

Then I used JavaScript (jQuery in this case) to get the height.  Next, also with jQuery, I set the display to block and the height to the 'closed' setting I needed.  Finally, I used the acquired height in my .animation to slide the div 'open.'

The CSS code:

```
#main_description {
position: relative;
display: none;
/*height: 8.92855em; -> this was the original 'closed' height*/ 
border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a5a6;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
var state = true;
var descriptionHeight = $("#main_description").height();
// for testing -> alert("Description Height: " + descriptionHeight);

$("#main_description").css({"display" : "block", "height" : "8.92855em"});

$("#main_description_toggle").click(function()
{
    if (state)
    {
        $("#main_description").animate({
        height: descriptionHeight + "px"
        }, 1000);

        $("#main_description_toggle").html("<a>less &#9650;</a>");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#main_description").animate({
        height: "8.92855em"
        }, 1000);

        $("#main_description_toggle").html("<a>more &#9660;</a>");
    }
    state = !state;
});
```

(I know, the height of 8.92855em seems weird, but that is 5x the line height and the client wanted 5 lines of text to show when the div is 'closed').