# Div does not take full height with jquery animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four boxes on a page, when the user hovers over them the box extends in height and some more text show up. The boxes have a different amount of text in them and the box needs to grow in height just enough the show all the text. I am using jquery animate to do this, but when I animate the box to extend to 100% in height there is still text that is outside of the box.

How to make the box extend to the full height of the text. Thank you

HTML:

```
<div id="cat">
        <div class="about_box">
            <div>
                <h1>Product <br /> Innovation</h1>
                <p>There are important issues to fix in the world.  True innovation in the product medium is about functional innovation-
                performing new jobs for consumers.  They are the physical proof of the brand, but if designed well, also a core brand message themselves,
                and emotional as well as physical beacon.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cat{
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 960px;
}

.about_box{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 190px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
    float:left;
    margin-right:25px;
}

.about_box > div {
    background-color: #191919;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 160px;
    z-index: 100;  
}

.about_box > div h1{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 25px;    
}

.about_box > div p{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 170px;
    height:100%;
}

.about_box:nth-child(1) > div:hover{
    background-color:gold;   
}

.about_box:nth-child(1) >div:hover p{
    color:black;
}

.about_box:nth-child(1) >div:hover h1{
    color:black;    
}
```

jQuery

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.about_box > div').hover(function() {
        $(this).clearQueue().parent().css('z-index', '10000')
        $(this).clearQueue().find("p").css('display', 'block')
        $(this).animate({
            width: 160, height: "100%", margin: 0,
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).clearQueue().parent().css('z-index', '100')
        $(this).clearQueue().find("p").css('display', 'none')
        $(this).animate({
            width: 160, height: 150, margin: 0,
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().css('z-index', '0');
        });
    });
      });
```

And the jsiffdle http://jsfiddle.net/2W2dQ/

Comment: It looks like `.about_box > div` is expanding to the height of its container `.about_box` (190px) plus its 20px padding.

Comment: Yes you are right, when I removed the height/width from .about_box it works, but the animation is not good. How to fix that (jsfiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/2W2dQ/11/)

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504755/animating-a-div-to-100-height

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of css and jquery. Like `.slideToggle()` This way you can still support IE9 and below

http://jsfiddle.net/uxkDC/

Comment: I would change `$('.about_box p').slideToggle()` to `$('p', this).slideToggle()`. Otherwise, you get funny effects when you have two or more `about_box`es. See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxkDC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to use JavaScript at all for this problem. Using CSS `transition` you can achieve the same effect with less code and complexity: http://jsfiddle.net/2W2dQ/18/